# Can I upgrade from 8.04 to 12.04?

Tags: upgrade

How can I upgrade from Hardy to 12.04 LTS directly?  Without doing multiple upgrades i.e to Lucid, Natty Narwhal, Oneiric, next upgrade, etc.

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible, you need to upgrade to 10.04 first, and then 12.04.

It might be quicker to just reinstall.